DisableIMDSv1: true option not available in launchconfiguration in aws
I've created new AWS account 3 days back and I am trying to deploy one sample elastic beanstalk application and it shows me autoscaling error.
In the AWS document I found that to create configuration file that will place at .ebextensions/launch-template.config and it contains
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    DisableIMDSv1: true

It give me error "DisableIMDSv1: true option not available in launchconfiguration"
